# Filling in polygon in matrix

Tags: matlab, geometry

In Matlab, I have a boolean matrix of zeros, and a list of points.

E.g.:

```
matrix = zeros(x, y);
points = [x1 y1; x2 y2; x3 y3; x4 y4];
```

How do I set all the bits in the matrix enclosed by the polygon formed by these points?

I'm aware of the [fill function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) but that seems to just plot the shape rather than filling in the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [inpolygon](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) or [poly2mask](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html) matlab functions.

Comment: inpolygon appears to do something else (convoluted use could achieve this I suppose), but poly2mask is perfect, thanks!